# MS Access Create Query with x number of fields depending on other table's key

Tags: ms-access, select, sum, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a query to sumarize weekly sales. I have two teams of sales force (could be more in time) and salesperson assigned to each team. I need to calculate sales % per team and individually within the team.

I'd like to have a permanent query instead of a VBA generated. I know I can create a Temp table using a VB generated CREATE and INSERT statements but the table would not be updated as the information is being added to the sales table.

After this query is created I will need to construct at least two more queries where percentages from that data are calculated as that information will be required at the time a form is opened.

The resulting query should output something like the following sample, considering that the week range could be filtered in the WHERE clause from Week 1 to Week Y and have ALL ID_SALES (from 1 to X) rows from SALESTEAM table  be each a column of its own.

```
    This are the tables to extract the data from

    TABLE Sales
          ID as AutoNumber
          ID_CUSTOMER AS Number
          ID_SALES as Number
          SaleDate as Date/Time
          SalesAmt as Currency
    END TABLE

    TABLE SALESTEAM
          ID_SALES as AutoNumber
          Name as String
          StartDate as Date/Time
          EndDate as Date/Time
          Active as Yes/No
          AssignedTo as Number
    END TABLE

    This would be a sample construct of the SELECT if made statically for the current records in SalesTeam Table using the All ID_Sales from all records

SELECT DatePart("yyyy", SalesDate) as SalesYear, DatePart("ww", SalesDate) as SalesWeek, 
           (SUM(SalesAmt) FROM SALES WHERE ID_Sales = 1 AND SalesDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) as Sales1,
           (SUM(SalesAmt) FROM SALES WHERE ID_Sales = 2 AND SalesDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) as Sales2,
           (SUM(SalesAmt) FROM SALES WHERE ID_Sales = 3 AND SalesDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) as Sales3,
           ...
           (SUM(SalesAmt) FROM SALES WHERE ID_Sales = X AND SalesDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) as SalesX
    FROM Sales GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesWeek ORDER BY SalesYear, SalesWeek

    +------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | WEEK |                              ID_SALES                                |
    +------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | WEEK |         1        |         2        |     ...     |         X        |
    +------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
    +  W1  |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |     ...     |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |
    +      | WK1 ID_SALES = 1 | WK1 ID_SALES = 2 |     ...     | WK1 ID_SALES = X |
    +------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
    |      |                  |                  |             |                  |
    +------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
    +  WY  |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |     ...     |  SUM(SALESAMT)   |
    +      | WKY ID_SALES = 1 | WKY ID_SALES = 2 |     ...     | WKY ID_SALES = X |
    +------+------------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Comment: And what is your question? You seem to have a query doing this already.

Comment: The SalesTeam table will be increased in time as the final user will not be able to change the query by himself. This needs to be dynamic.

Comment: It is difficult to give you an answer without knowing the schema these two tables.

Comment: Schema edited into original post

Comment: I think you can do it with a [Crosstab Query](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html). You can write it in SQL or do it in the query designer.

Comment: You did not show raw data sample in question. What you do show looks like a CROSSTAB result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your desired output is structured as a cross-tab style query.  Access Cross-Tab queries are buggy and difficult to bind to reports if you don't know exactly how many columns (salespersons in this case) you will have.  I suggest outputting a standard report first then going back and making a Cross-Tab Version. That said lets start with a more appropriate and normalized table structure like:
[image]
The SalesPersonTeam table implements a many to many relationship between SalesPersons and Teams.  Your free to add teams, and Salespersons and move Salespersons between teams as much as you like.
Your first query will be:
[image]

which for my StarTrek Data gives ($ stands for gold pressed latinum):
[image]
Note CrossTab is selected instead of Select.

To get a percent instead of a sum you will have to work around a bug:
[image]
but note the make table tab is selected access can't run a cross tab query with a calculated column based on a dlookup so make a temporary table.  then base the crosstab on the temporary table.  to clean up use a form to load the report and have the form create the tempoary table.  delete the temporary table in the reports close event.
here is the crosstab to get the percents and the results:
[image]
[image]

to get a crosstab of the team based results just change the query like so:
[image]
follow the same procedure you did before to get a crosstab with percents.
If you stick with a crosstab based report you will have to make some decisions about how to handle the variable number of columns

Comment: Thanks mazoula... I've been doodling around and kind of get the feel on how to tweek the TRANSFORMT...PIVOT statement to my needs. This statement is the answer to my original question. I've been doing a few queries to get to the query from which the CrossTab will get it's data. Haven't gotten to reports but I will keep your advice in mind while designing them.